# How do you turn off share history when using ShareActionProvider?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

The new ShareActionProvider available in Android 4.0 (or in earlier versions if you're using ActionBarSherlock) has a feature where the last used item is displayed in the action bar. Is there anyway to turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to do this. However, the class is really simple and you could very easily create your own version of `ShareActionProvider` that did not keep a history. You would just have to determine the sort order of the possible targets using some other means of ordering (e.g., alphabetically).

Comment: The thing is, I want to keep the history, but ONLY in the dropdown menu. Adding the extra icon is annoying and it doesn't fit in the bar anymore.

Comment: @phreakhead Take a look at my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17290249/1446466 . It will help your need.

Answer (score 21):

For me, the best solution for avoid the history icon is don't use ShareActionProvider, instead of it, create it as any other action:

```
 <item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_action_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
    android:title="@string/share"/>
```

at the menu/activity_actions.xml put a item with the ic_action_share icon...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

Inflate the menu normally...

```
private void actionShare(){
     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     i.setType("text/plain");
     i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my string");
     i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "another string");
     startActivity(i); 
     //Or like above will always display the chooser
     //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getResources().getText(R.string.share))); 
 }
```

Create a method with an ACTION_SEND intent

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            actionShare();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

And finally call to this method from onOptionsItemSelected

more info ->[Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Comment: This is even better than the traditional ActionProvider.

Comment: This *is* better than the native `ShareActionProvider` because it doesn't display history but *all* apps that can share.

Answer (score 13):

Start the share activity by yourself:

```
shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
shareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
    // start activity ourself to prevent search history
    context.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Then the ShareActionProvider will not add the chosen activity to the share history.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works for others. When using the v7 compat library, it will still crash with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No preceding call to #readHistoricalData`. Furthermore, the documentation clearly states this for `onShareTargetSelected`: "Note: You should not handle the intent here. This callback aims to notify the client that a sharing is being performed, so the client can update the UI if necessary. The return result is ignored. Always return false for consistency."

Comment: Remember to clean the data of your application in the device for testing.

Comment: @Felix's comment is valid. Docs say this shouldn't be done. I end up with 2 intents fired.

Answer (score 4):

I created my own version of the ShareActionProvider (and supporting classes), you can copy them into your project (https://gist.github.com/saulpower/10557956).  This not only adds the ability to turn off history, but also to filter the apps you would like to share with (if you know the package name).

```
private final String[] INTENT_FILTER = new String[] {
        "com.twitter.android",
        "com.facebook.katana"
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.journal_entry_menu, menu);

    // Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    if (shareItem instanceof SupportMenuItem) {
        mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(this);
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(ShareUtils.share(mJournalEntry));
        mShareActionProvider.setIntentFilter(Arrays.asList(INTENT_FILTER));
        mShareActionProvider.setShowHistory(false);
        ((SupportMenuItem) shareItem).setSupportActionProvider(mShareActionProvider);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Point of clarification:  It's not the "last used", it's "most often used", across a sliding window period of time.

If you prefer not to use history, then before creating your views, call

```
yourShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
```

Description of this method, from the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html#setShareHistoryFileName%28java.lang.String%29) (emphasis mine):

> Sets the file name of a file for persisting the share history which history will be used for ordering share targets. This file will be used for all view created by onCreateActionView(). Defaults to DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME. **Set to null if share history should not be persisted between sessions**.

EDIT:  I should clarify — The "most often used" item won't show up if there's no history, so this is currently the only way of removing that button.

Comment: Can you be more specific, in what you mean by "didn't work" ?

Comment: I got the same behavior. The sharing was still working..which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: When I call setShareHistoryFileName(null), the share action doesn't do anything any longer :(

Comment: When I set the filename null on a Nexus 7 running 4.2.1, the default action button correctly disappears. However, attempting to choose an action from the share menu yields a crash with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No preceding call to #readHistoricalData`.

Comment: This causes a crash on my system

Comment: Causes crash after selecting a share app: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No preceding call to #readHistoricalData
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel  (Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.3)

Answer (score 0):

Although It's been 2 years ago today but I'd like to share my experience as I made a custom ShareActionProvider class and add this line `chooserView.getDataModel().setHistoryMaxSize(0);` inside onCreateActionView() which did all the magic for me ! .. I tested it on Lollipop device and on API 16 emulator device and it works perfectly. here is my custom class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.view.View;


public class MyShareActionProvider extends ShareActionProvider {
    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param context Context for accessing resources.
     */
    public MyShareActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView() {
        ActivityChooserView chooserView = (ActivityChooserView) super.onCreateActionView();
        Drawable icon;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            icon = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.share_icon);
        }else{
            icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.share_icon);
        }
        chooserView.setExpandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable(icon);
        chooserView.getDataModel().setHistoryMaxSize(0);
        return chooserView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice, but in `androidx` the `setHistoryMaxSize()` method is inaccessible... :(

Comment: @l33t You are right.. I discovered that even earlier since appcompat v.23 library

Answer (score -1):

add the code like this:

```
    private void addShareSelectedListener() {
    if (null == mShareActionProvider) return;
    OnShareTargetSelectedListener listener = new OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
            mContex.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    };

//Set to null if share history should not be persisted between sessions.
    mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
    mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(listener);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_action_provider, menu);

    // Set file with share history to the provider and set the share intent.
    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar);
    ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem.getActionProvider();
    ***actionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
    OnShareTargetSelectedListener listener = new OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    };
    actionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(listener);***
```