# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_share.png"

Tags: android, numberformatexception, android-imagebutton

There is a ShareActionProvider button with custom image on action bar. In addition ShareActionProvider code is modified ([How to hide the share action (which use most) icon near the share action provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755465/how-to-hide-the-share-action-which-use-most-icon-near-the-share-action-provide), https://gist.github.com/saulpower/10557956).  On several phones (Samsung Galaxy S3 - Android 4.1, Huawei G730-U10 - Android 4.2) crash occures.

File ic_action_share.png exists in folders  drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi,drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi. Why does Android request this image from v4 folder (java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_share.png")?

Stack:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setCustomView(ActionBarImpl.java:330)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_action_share.png"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:260)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_action_share.png"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3561)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:432)
at com.example.trace.CustomShareActionProvider.ActivityChooserView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.example.trace.CustomShareActionProvider.ActivityChooserView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.example.trace.CustomShareActionProvider.ActivityChooserView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.example.trace.CustomShareActionProvider.ShareActionProvider.onCreateActionView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.view.j.onCreateActionView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.y.onCreateActionView(Unknown Source)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:580)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.t.getActionView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.view.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.example.trace.p.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.n.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.h.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.m.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.g.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v7.a.n.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:445)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:819)
at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)
...
```

style.xml

```
<style name="app_theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomShareIcon</item>
    ...
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme" tools:targetApi="14">@style/CustomShareIcon</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomShareIcon" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
    <item name="*android:actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_action_share</item>
</style>
```

Comment: do you have ic_action_share.png in xhdp foler

Comment: yes, I have ic_action_share.png in folders drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi. But why Android with API version 16 requests image for API 4+, while there is file for all API's?

Answer (score 0):

try this

add image **ic_action_share.png** in your `res/drawable-hdpi-v4/` folder

v-4 is version 4 so it access only v-4 folders automatically.

Comment: but thats the question, why we should put v4 folder also when we have drawable-xxhdpi/xhdpi/hdpi ??? why android looking into v4?

Comment: @Farhan did you arrive to a conclusion on this one?

Comment: I was facing this issue when deleted a image resource explicitly. cleaning project solve my problem.