# How to remove the 'most used App' Icon

Tags: android

How to remove the 'most used App' Icon from the ActionBar beside Share Icon?
I am using ShareActionProvider...
When I use the Share icon for first time, after that it displays the App that was used last time...
It looks ugly....

[image]

Comment: post sheen-shot and you question is not clear what exactly want to remove?

Comment: This it exactly what you want. Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17290249/6127411

Comment: @jankigadhiya Thanks, will report after Trying :)