# ShareActionProvider on the Contextual Action Bar (CAB)

Tags: java, android, contextual-action-bar, shareactionprovider

I'm using the Contextual Action Bar on my listview in multi mode.

During the onCreateActionMode of the CAB I initialize the ShareActionProvider.
Here is the corresponding snippet:

```
private class modeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_history_detail, menu);
        // Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
        shareAction();
        return true;
    }
```

The shareAction method:

```
public void shareAction() {

    sb = new StringBuilder();

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(History_DetailActivity.this);
    String shareMessageHeader = sharedPref.getString("pref_dialog_share_header_default_value", getString(R.string.pref_dialog_share_header_default_value));

    sb.append(shareMessageHeader);
    sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    for (long id : checkedIDs) {

        Cursor cursor2 = dbHelper.getWork(id);
        if (cursor2 != null && cursor2.getCount() > 0 && !cursor2.isClosed()) {
            sb.append(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(Consts.colWerkUren_Date)) + " ");
            sb.append(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(Consts.colWerkUren_Werkbon)) + " ");
            sb.append(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(Consts.colWerkUren_Type)) + " ");
            sb.append(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(Consts.colWerkUren_Comment)) + " ");
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        cursor2.close();
    }

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sb.toString());
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

}
```

If I use it like this, the StringBuilder variable sb is updated but the ShareActionProvider Intent is not.
I tried using the method defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281251/2119391
But according the documentation the onShareTargetSelected method doesn't allow any changes to the Intent:

> Called when a share target has been selected. The client can decide
>   whether to perform some action before the sharing is actually
>   performed.
>
> **Note: Modifying the intent is not permitted and any changes to the
>   latter will be ignored.**
>
> Note: You should not handle the intent here. This callback aims to
>   notify the client that a sharing is being performed, so the client can
>   update the UI if necessary.

Resulting in a not up to date StringBuilder sb when sharing because of the initialization of the share intent (and thus the intent extra's) in the onCreateActionMode method.

I temporarely solved the issue via very ugly (but working) code:
Calling the initialization of the share intent in the onItemCheckedStateChanged in the modeCallback of the MultiChoiceModeListener.

Code snippet:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        if (checked) {
            checkedIDs.add(id);
            selCount++;
        } else {
            checkedIDs.remove(id);
            selCount--;
        }

        // invalidate the CAB to be able to hide and show menu items
        mode.invalidate();

        // TODO Very dirty way of using the share action provider
        // Is being called every change of a checked list view row
        // Otherwise the share intent isn't up to date
        shareAction();
    }
```