# Delete Last Item of Share Action Provider

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I have implement the ShareActionProvider in my Android Application. This work fine, but i want to delete the icon of the last item that used, at the right of the button, like this :

[image]

This is my configuration :

Menu :

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.MyShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Partager"/>
```

Activity :

```
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(mShareIntent);
    }
```

Do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: You mean at some point in your program/code, you want to make it invisible?

Comment: Yes i want to make invisible the icon of the last shared options selected

Comment: This discussion might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706564/how-do-you-turn-off-share-history-when-using-shareactionprovider

Comment: It Work but not in Fragment..