# How to resolve import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListPopupWindow?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I was trying to use the snippet from 2nd answer of the following post:
[How do you turn off share history when using ShareActionProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706564/how-do-you-turn-off-share-history-when-using-shareactionprovider)

Which can be dowloaded from [here](https://gist.github.com/saulpower/10557956) and after adding `ActivityChooserView.java` along with other files to my project, I cannot resolve:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListPopupWindow;
```

Import of `android.support.v7.appcompat` does not give any errors.

Where can I find `android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListPopupWindow` class?

I googled it and found nothing :)

I am compiling for android v23 and using appcompat.v7 of the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow.java) the package name is `android.support.v7.widget`, so the correct import is:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow;
```

`ListPopupWindow` was moved from `android.support.v7.internal.widget` to `android.support.v7.widget` in v7 appcompat library v21.0.0.

To fix the issue change the import to the updated one.

Comment: Thanks Mattia, I tried that before in Eclipse but it didn't work, however after migrating to the fresh Android studio from the not very up to date Eclipse ADT it allowed me to compile and create apk!