# How to fix the share icon in the support actionbar

Tags: android, xamarin, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to implement the share functionality within my app. So far it works fine and I can share text to all other apps. The problem is the way it's shown.

I want something like just the share icon visible and then when user taps on it, it opens the OS dialog and lets user choose the app they want to share content to.

```
    var share_article = menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.action_share);
    var share_article_provider = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.ShareActionProvider) Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat.GetActionProvider (share_article);
    share_article_provider.SetShareIntent (CreateIntent ());
```

and the xml:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="share"
    myapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

My app currently looks like this:

[image]

There's also a white border around it that I don't like.
Is there any way to change the icon??

How do I fix it??

Comment: you mean you do not want to have the smm icon?just the share icon is enough?

Comment: @penkzhou, Yes, that's exactly what I mean. When user clicks on share it opens the share dialog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33645599/5173926) when using support library this can be fixed really easily. This method won't turn off the share history but will hide the icons from actionbar.
I just needed to subclass the `Android.Support.V7.Widget.ShareActionProvider` like the following: (C# using Xamarin)

```
public class MyShareActionProvider : Android.Support.V7.Widget.ShareActionProvider
{
    public SingleArticleShareActionProvider (Context context) : base (context)
    {}

    public override View OnCreateActionView ()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then inside `OnCreateOptionsMenu` use the `MyShareActionProvider` like:

```
var share_article = menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.action_share);
var share = new SingleArticleShareActionProvider (globalContext);

Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat.SetActionProvider (share_article, share);
share_article.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha);
share.SetShareIntent (CreateIntent ());
```

You can use any icon you like with the method `SetIcon`.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to turn off your share history.There is no official API to do this, but you can make your own `ShareActionProvider`. Actually there are two similar question on SO:

1. [How do you turn off share history when using ShareActionProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706564/how-do-you-turn-off-share-history-when-using-shareactionprovider)
2. [How to hide the share action (which use most) icon near the share action provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755465/how-to-hide-the-share-action-which-use-most-icon-near-the-share-action-provide/17290249#17290249)

Wish these could help you.